# mod_proxy_balancer does not remove dead servers

Tags: load-balancing, mod-proxy

We use the current configuration (slightly obfuscated) to balance 2 web servers against 4 application (Tomcat) servers, using JSESSIONID; each web server has this exact same configuration for mod_proxy

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.0.1:8009 route=app0
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.0.2:8009 route=app1
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.0.3:8009 route=app2
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.0.4:8009 route=app3

ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

We are seeing that if an application server is totally unreachable, either via NIC removal in VMWare or shutting down the server, some web servers will still route to it even after the 60 seconds for Retry.  This of course causes issues for users who have been routed to that now-dead application server.

However, if we merely shut down Tomcat on the application servers, mod_proxy removes them from the pool within 60 seconds and properly shifts the traffic to a living server. Of course if we manually remove it via balancer-manager it immediately stops routing but manual intervention is not acceptable.

I've been looking through the documentation but I don't see any parameters that have not been set that would cause this to happen.  I can't imagine that mod_proxy is just so stupid that this is default behavior.  What could we be missing in this specific configuration?

I hope this isn't a really obvious and glaring misconfiguration, so any help is greatly appreciated.